# Switch between 2 or more templates with an action in controllers?

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a default Phoenix application. This app will have a `page_controller`
which will load an `index.html.eex` file.

The app will know to use the `view` to access `templates/page/index.html.eex`.

Now say you have created another html page which is identical to `index.html.eex` in every way except it is in French.

As we do not want to create a whole new Phoenix application which will have all the same code, with the exception being the French translation of the current `page/index.html.eex`, is there a way to tell 
the view or the controller which file needs to be loaded.

Is there a plug which can be placed in the router to alter where `render` will look for it's templates?

Comment: Is the French `index.html.eex` stored in the same folder (with different file name) or a separate one? Do you have a separate View module for each translation for each controller?

Comment: I was planning to have 2 folders in the templates directory. One for all the English templates and the other which will contain all the French templates

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest you to use Gettext to use labels for French pages.

For example you can all French templates keep in the very same folders (to don't change logic for view), but to name them with suffix eg. "index_fr.html.eex" etc. and then you can write quite simple helper (not necessarily a plug) that will add to all of your templates this suffix.

Still, I would recommend you using Gettext - template's source code is only in place and almost all of the logic Gettext handles for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pick the @patnowak's answer. Use Gettext, that's the tool made for translation and is powerful enough.

If you still want to do it, remember `render/3` in controller calls `render/2` functions defined in views, if defined. If not, it runs default rendering function and looks for the template. Read [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html) for more information.

So for example, this is the controller:

```
def index(conn, params) do
  # defined assigns as you wish
  render(conn, "index.html", assigns)
end
```

Now, define this in the view:

```
def render("index.html, assigns) do
  case assigns[:lang] do
    "fr" -> render("index_fr.html", assigns)
    _others -> render("index_en.html", assigns)
  end
end
```

You may also write a plug to automatically put `:lang` into assigns:

```
def lang_plug(conn, opts) do
  conn
  |> fetch_query_params()
  |> (fn cn -> assign(cn, :lang, cn.query_params[:lang] || "en").()
end
```

Look [Plug.Conn](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html) to see docs of `fetch_query_params/1` and `assign/3`, and also other functions to fetch language from other places like headers or body.

You get the idea. In the plug, fill assigns with `:lang`, fetch them inside your defined render function and act appropriately.

Still, *Don't do this*. Using Gettext is the proper way.